# Error in starting Rails Passenger App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I changed ruby version to 2.1.5 with RVM, configured 4 rails App with Apache, but I can't start them with Passenger. So I got this error everytime.

```
App 8612 stderr: Cannot execute "/root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-5.0.8/buildout/support-binaries/PassengerAgent": Permission denied (errno=13)
[ 2015-06-01 20:11:43.2847 8422/7f244835b700 App/Implementation.cpp:287 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/example: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: 2862c35c
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-pKDVAi.html
  Message from application: Cannot execute "/root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-5.0.8/buildout/support-binaries/PassengerAgent": Permission denied (errno=13)


[ 2015-06-01 20:11:43.2889 8422/7f2449b9f700 age/Hel/Req/CheckoutSession.cpp:252 ]: [Client 2-1] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 2862c35c. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

How should I correct situation? I use `chown -R 777 /root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-5.0.8/buildout/support-binaries/` , but problem last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not run your application with the root user.

Add `PassengerUserSwitching on` to your virtual host. If your web app is owned by root, it should be able to use rvm (as it is installed for root user only).